# Dot after location list. Glossaries

Tags: pdftex, glossaries

I want to have a dot in glossary after all page numbers as it shown on the image:

[image: screenshot with mark]

Code for this document below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{utc}{name=UTC, description={Coordinated Universal Time}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
Some \gls{utc} text here

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

```
makeglossaries glossaries-example && pdflatex glossaries-example.tex
```

I google, briefly looks to the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), but didn't found anything for that, hope I miss something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i hoped for a more generally solution, but could not find a hint within the documentation. That said please see code below and find more about custom styles in doc's section 15.2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{utc}{name=UTC, description={Coordinated Universal Time}}

\newglossarystyle{myList}{%
    \setglossarystyle{list}% 
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
        \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2.}% dot inserted here after 2nd argument
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
    Some \gls{utc} text here
    
    \printglossary[style=myList]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. just note for future readers: \printglossarIES replaced to \printglossarY